# Dropping through a platform in Clickteam Fusion 2.5

Tags: physics, platform, clickteam-fusion

I am using Clickteam Multimedia Fusion 2.5. Currently, I have a rudimentary platformer game, with the following setup:

- player object is set as a **physics platform**, with the **physics engine** added to make it all work
- the floor is a **quick backdrop**, with the obstacle type of **obstacle**
- the only platform in the game is also a quick backdrop, with the obstacle type of **platform**

The way the game is setup, the player object can jump through the platform.

**WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO**

Is there a default, built-in way for the player object to be able to drop down through the platform? To be more specific, is there a default key press or a default combination of keys which would allow the player object to drop down through the platform?

I guess I could add it all in via the Event Editor, but I was wondering if there's a built-in way which handles it all.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Wasn't sure if it was the right thing to do. Answering my own question, I mean.

Comment: Answering your own question is a perfectly acceptable. What's not accepted are link only answers. The owner of the link may take down the video which makes the post totally irrelevant and useless for this site. This is why we like complete and descriptive answers, they have a better value for the future.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Thank you for the explanation. I hadn't considered that possibility. I have edited my answer with an explanation and a screenshot of the solution. Would that be enough to undelete it?

Comment: I think you could flag either the answer or the question about it (flag for moderator attention). Not sure what's the proper way to do this though :/

Comment: For future reference, I would just re-post the answer instead. There's no review queue or other automated notice that you've changed an answer that was deleted, so it's unlikely to get seen, and re-posted the answer with improvements is perfectly acceptable. In this case I did randomly stumble across this question against and undeleted your edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have been unable to find a default way to achieve what I had in mind, so I ended up using a variant of what was explained in Sparckman's YouTube video, called **Indiana Jones - Falling Through Platforms - Tutorial**. I'm afraid that I had to delete the link, in order to be able to post a picture. See below.

The trick was to group the lines handling player collisions with platforms, and introduce switches and a counter. Whenever the player presses down arrow, the counter is set to 25, and the Collisions group gets deactivated. Immediately after that, the game starts reducing the counter down to zero. When the counter goes down to zero, the game checks if the Collisions group is deactivated. If it is, the game activates it.

The explanation is (I hope) clearer, once you take a look at the Event Editor:

[image: With the properties window for the counter object on the bottom]

Perhaps not the most elegant of ways to solve this issue, but it worked for me.